# Calculate the S1 sum for variance of Moran's I

Tags: r, spatial

I would like to calculate the `S1` term for the variance of Moran's I. The following is the formula to calculate the `S1`

[image: S1 formula]

where w_{ij} is an element in the spatial weights matrix.

My spatial weights matrix is as following:-

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1, 0.1, 0.166666666666667,
0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0.125, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.1,
0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0909090909090909,
0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111,
0.125, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909,
0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0.125,
0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667,
0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333,
0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111,
0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0.111111111111111,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909,
0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1, 0.1, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111,
0.125, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1, 0.1,
0.166666666666667, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1,
0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.111111111111111,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1,
0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0.0909090909090909, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1,
0.111111111111111, 0.125, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111,
0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0, 0.1,
0.1, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.1, 0.111111111111111, 0.125, 0,
0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909,
0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1,
0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(20L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("AUS", "BEL", "CAN", "CHE", "DEU", "DNK", "ESP", "FIN",
    "FRA", "GBR", "IRL", "ITA", "JPN", "KOR", "NLD", "NOR", "NZL",
    "PRT", "SWE", "USA"), c("AUS", "BEL", "CAN", "CHE", "DEU",
    "DNK", "ESP", "FIN", "FRA", "GBR", "IRL", "ITA", "JPN", "KOR",
    "NLD", "NOR", "NZL", "PRT", "SWE", "USA")))
```

I can do this by using a for loop within a for loop, but I am thinking that there might be a more efficient way to do this. Maybe using lapply or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me, the solution looks like this

```r
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), size = 16, replace = TRUE), nrow = 4) 
diag(m) <- 0
m
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    1    1    0
#> [2,]    1    0    1    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    0
S1 <- 0.5 * sum((m + t(m))^2)
S1
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Define a squared sum function and use `outer`.

```
squared_sum <- function(x, y) (x + y)^2
sum(outer(W, W, squared_sum))/2
#[1] 3037.03
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `expand.grid`

```
squared_sum <- function(x, y) (x + y)^2
with(expand.grid(W, W) , sum(squared_sum(Var1, Var2)))/2
[1] 3037.03
```